# Creating a 360° panorama from a deep zoom image in Silverlight?

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I created a deep zoom image with Silverlight 3.0, but I want to make it into a 360° image. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this post](http://blog.blueboxes.co.uk/2009/08/31/creating-a-360-degree-panorama-in-silverlight/) that will explain how to create a 360 view in silverlight.

Using the [Deep Zoom Composer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=457b17b7-52bf-4bda-87a3-fa8a4673f8bf&displaylang=en) you should be able to add deep zoom to your two half's of you image as you would for any other image.